# Windows 8/C# app to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8, drawing

I want to made an app: easy paint.  I know how to add images(as primitive layers) to grid/canvas or how to draw on it. My problem is how to save content of my grid/canvas into pdf? Is any method to save something like this to any popular format?

If it  is impossible how can I implement "drawing" elements (images,shapes) on grid and exporting work to pdf.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinRT - view and edit PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577007/winrt-view-and-edit-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

A third party control is the way to go at the moment (other than implementing the PDF spec. yourself).  I've seen some success with the [Foxit SDK for Windows 8 Store apps](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/mswin8metro/).